# Is a std::unique_ptr moved into a std::vector when using push_back?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stdvector, unique-ptr

I have a question about how a `std::unique_ptr` is inserted into a `std::vector`. Imagine I have a function that produces objects as follows:

```
std::unique_ptr<CObject> createObjects()
{
    return std::unique_ptr<CObject> (new CObject());
}
```

Now in my code, I have a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<CObjects>> vec` and I insert elements like so:

```
vec.push_back(createObjects());
```

Now my question is: Is the `unique_ptr` moved into the vector or is it copied?

Comment: `emplace_back` is more appropriate here.

Comment: Do you mean `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<CObject>>`?

Comment: Sorry! That is what I meant. I changed it.

@user2485710:  `emplace_back` looks very interessting, but I don't think I can use it in my application, because I have a template that creates objects that inherate from a base class and returns unique pointers to the base class. The vector stores those.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A `unique_ptr` cannot be copy-constructed or copy-assigned. In the case of a `push_back` into a vector, it is moved, provided it is an *rvalue*. To test this, you can try pushing an *lvalue*. This would require the `unique_ptr` to be copyable or assignable, and so would fail:

```
std::unique_ptr<CObject> p(new CObject());
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<CObject>> vec;
vec.push_back(p); // error!
vec.push_back(std::unique_ptr<CObject>(new CObject())); // OK
vec.push_back(std::move(p)); // OK
```